# Cannot open java programs I saved in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I had no problem running my java code in eclipse last week and I have no problem creating a new java application in eclipse. However, I am unable to open any of the java program files in eclipse that I saved. I checked to see if my jdk se development kit was removed from my computer by mistake and it is still there. What do you think is wrong? Why can't I open my old files? All of my java programs are saved as CLASS files.

Comment: Saved as class files?  So you didn't keep the source code?

Comment: They are source code because I write the code in the class file compile it and run it. All my class files are under one project name. I had no issues until today.

Answer (score 1):

Source files are normally saved with a `.java` extension.  Once you compile your source files, javac will generate you some files with a `.class` extension.  These are not source files, and are usually deleted and recreated every time you compile your code.  If you want to find your source code, you'll need to look for the `.java` files on your disk.

If you've deleted your `.java` files by accident, it is usually possible to decompile the class files into something resembling the original source, but much of the original formatting will be lost - comments etc.  This approach is far from ideal, but may help you recover the situation if you cannot recover the original source files.  A good decompiler can be found at http://jd.benow.ca/ - you can either download the standalone application, or it has plugins for Eclipse and IntelliJ.

Comment: I found my java files and open them (though it isn't the same way I opened them in eclipse initially because they were all in one project and they were classes) , I can see the code but now I can't run my programs. When I click the run button , It now asked me to select 'Build an Ant' and a prompt comes up saying that 'Built failed' . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To run a program, your class must have a "main" method which looks like the following:
`public static void main(String [] args) {...}`.  You should find your class with the main method in it, the right click on the class and do "Run as Java Application"

Answer (score 0):

Hi once you compile the source java files .java extn the class files will be created. Check your workspace in your disk there will be a folder as package as you created in eclipse under src folder.